# Echo is not working with HTML inside of php but working with php

Tags: php, html

This is working when I open it with ubuntu terminal

First.php

```
 <?php
    echo "My first PHP script!";
    ?>
```

But I have made one HTML with Same confiuration

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it in browser it shows empty

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Make file extension to php.

Comment: Thanks Praveen should I make html code extension to php?

Comment: Yes save file as `index.php` or something like that...And you also gonna need a local server to test a php script...

Comment: Now it is not opening in browser
As well as in terminal output is like
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

My first PHP script!
</body>
</html>

Comment: You can use html tags  in .php file

Comment: @AbhishekParikh you gonna need a `local server` to run a php file so download xampp and install it.....then you can test it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24423272/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a php extension on any webserver running that parses the script, you cant just input php to an html file and open this one. PHP is a serverside language not a clientside

Comment: Hey thanks for the understanding

Comment: but please can you let me know there are some sites with php extension ..
Are there HTML imported to PHP script?

Comment: like this one http://php.net/mirrors.php

Comment: You should really follow the official documentation for setting up your environment and then continue following the tutorial on how to write PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Save this file as for example mytest.php and run on the browser

output is :: My first PHP script

Try it OR you can run it from terminal as well

Answer (score -1):

Always save file with php extension if it has php code for Cor PHP. You can put HTML/javascript/css code inside a filename.php file but outside  tags, that will work fine.